# confusing myself with pointers and references, c++ (Getting mouse coords from WinAPI)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a class:

```
class Mouse
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    void MouseMove( int x, int y );
    Mouse();
};
```

I include it as a header file to my windows.cpp that contains WndProc and WinMain functions.
Just underneath that include I declare a static instance of my mouse:

```
#include "Mouse.h"
#include "Game.h"

static Mouse mouse;
```

My mouse methods look like this:

```
#include "Mouse.h"

void Mouse::MouseMove( int x, int y )
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}
```

On my WndProc I am processing WM_MOUSEMOUSE and passing the x and y values (which have correct values in through to my MouseMove function:

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            {

                int x = ( short )LOWORD( lParam );
                int y = ( short )HIWORD( lParam );


                bool leftButtonDown = wParam & MK_LBUTTON;
                bool rightButtonDown = wParam & MK_RBUTTON;

                mouse.MouseMove( x, y );

            }
            break;
```

My MouseMove function runs through and sets this->x to x successfully and the same with the y value. That is all... done.

Now, in my windows loop I am running my game (theGame.Go):

```
Game theGame = Game( hWnd );

    MSG msg;

    ZeroMemory( &msg, sizeof(msg) );

    while( msg.message!=WM_QUIT )
    {
       if( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE ) )
       {
          TranslateMessage( &msg );
          DispatchMessage( &msg );
       }
       else
       {
            theGame.Go();
       }
    }
```

My game header looks like this:

```
#include "Mouse.h"

    class Game
    {
    public:
        Game( HWND hWnd );
        ~Game();
        void Go();
        void ComposeFrame();

        LPD3DXSPRITE sprite;
        LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 gTexture;
        D3DXVECTOR3 pos;
    private:
        D3DGraphics gfx;
    };
```

My Game construct looks like this:

```
Game::Game( HWND hWnd )
    :
    gfx( hWnd )
{
    HRESULT result;

    sprite = NULL;
    result = D3DXCreateSprite( gfx.d3dDevice, &sprite );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    gTexture = NULL;
    result = D3DXCreateTextureFromFile( gfx.d3dDevice, "Images/character001.png", &gTexture );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    gfx.d3dDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
};
```

The game object has no idea that the mouse object declared in my windows.cpp exists regardless of the fact I have declared it globally there. So I think to myself, I need to pass the mouse object by reference into my Game object. I start by modifying the windows loop like so:

```
Game theGame = Game( hWnd, &mouse );

    MSG msg;

    ZeroMemory( &msg, sizeof(msg) );

    while( msg.message!=WM_QUIT )
    {
       if( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE ) )
       {
          TranslateMessage( &msg );
          DispatchMessage( &msg );
       }
       else
       {
            theGame.Go();
       }
    }
```

Now I add a few parameters to my Game.h class so that I have a reference to the memory and can get the *mouse.x from it later...:

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game( HWND hWnd, Mouse &mouse );
...
```

I go back to look at my windows loop and there's a squiggly under my call:

```
Game theGame = Game( hWnd, &mouse );
```

which states that:

```
6   IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "Game::Game" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (HWND, Mouse *) c:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Game\Game\Windows.cpp  75  17  Game
```

I don't get it? How on earth do I just change one global instance of my mouse and call it from within my god damn Game object :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared your `Game::Game` constructor as taking a reference to a `Mouse` but you are passing it a pointer.

Either change to:

```
Game::Game(HWND hWnd, Mouse* mouse);
```

or:

```
Game(hWnd, mouse);
```

Also note that when you call your `Game` constructor, you are actually making an unnecessary copy:

```
Game theGame = Game( hWnd, &mouse );
```

Instead, change this to:

```
Game theGame( hWnd, &mouse );
```

Comment: I have done this Mouse* mouse... and my Game methods other than the constructor cannot see this object, So I declared a Mouse mouse in my Game.h and then set the constructor default value to mouse( mouse ), my intellisense shutup with its pube looking squiggles but the mouse.x and y are still not coming through regardless of the fact I now have a class local version of it?

Comment: I've now managed to change it round so in my windows loop I call Game theGame( hWnd, mouse ); and then I receive a reference in my Game construct parameters.. this works great too!

Answer (score 1):

The problem that's causing your error is that your `Game` constructor takes a *reference* to `Mouse`:

```
Game( HWND hWnd, Mouse &mouse );
```

You, however, are passing a *pointer* to `Mouse` by taking the address of `mouse`:

```
Game theGame = Game( hWnd, &mouse );
```

You can change one or the other: either change the parameter type to a pointer (`Mouse* mouse`) or pass `mouse` as the argument.

However, this is an atypical approach to having a global object. By declaring `mouse` as `static`, you are giving it internal linkage and it cannot be accessed in any other translation unit. What you would generally do is have the following declaration in a single header file which you will include whenever you need access to the global `mouse` object:

```
extern Mouse mouse;
```

And then in a single implementation file provide the definition:

```
Mouse mouse;
```

Comment: I added a header file called Globals.h, in that I have placed #pragma once and extern Mouse mouse. In my Windows.cpp I have included the #Globals.h and also in my Game file... In my Windows.cpp I have made an instance of it Mouse mouse. Now in my game object x and y are coming out as - mouse{x=-858993460 y=-858993460 } and they are un-changing.

Comment: In my MouseMove function, x and y are still being passed correctly, but once again my Game object does not see their values.. only NULL values of -859blabla etc. Can I pass you my project somehow?